# Python URL Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, http-post, http-method

Let me start by saying I am *extremely* new to Python, but I am familiar with other programming languages. Before I dive into this project, I need to ask a few questions.

**I need to be able to make URL GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE requests straight out of Python.**

I'll be writing a library for specific use cases of those functions and I don't want users to have to go installing external libraries (like "Requests").

**What is the best way to do this, urllib.request?**

Thank you for educating me.

Comment: First of all writing an additional module for the known thing is literally unnecessary. And If you are not willing to instruct the user to download them seperately, You can handle that installation within your script itself. Otherwise urllib will help you to develop your own module for the same.

Comment: We're doing other things besides just url requests within the functions so it's not unnecessary. I dont want to write something that depends on an external library so I guess i'll go with urllib2.

Comment: Then you can go with developing your own. The fact is it will be easier to incorporate your changes with the standard libraries. Nothing else is the concern :)

Comment: **`urlib2`** isn't in Python 3. It's now [**`urllib.request`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html). I'm not sure of your question. Is there some problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to make URL GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE requests straight out of Python. ... What is the best way to do this, urllib2?

Since [*urllib.request.urlopen()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) is hard-wired to GET or POST, you will need  [*http.client.HTTPConnection*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpconnection-objects) instead:

```
import http.client
import pprint

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.jython.org')
c = conn.request('HEAD', '/index.html')
r = conn.getresponse()

pprint.pprint(r.getheaders())
print('Size of body:', len(r.read()))
```

The technique gets you "closer to the metal" and gives more control, but it 
loses all the comforts of *urllib.request* and its various highlevel services (like following redirects).

Comment: what about urllib2.Request.get_method?

Comment: @JoeBlow The *urllib2.Request.get_method()* only returns *GET* or *POST*.  There are no other options.